# Sitecore adding port numbers to all URLs

Tags: url, sitecore, port-number

Wondering if anyone has seen this behavior before. My instance of Sitecore 6.6 appends the port number to all the URLs it generates for my site. So for example, a link to the home page should be "https://example.org", but instead it's generated as "https://example.org:443". Everything functions fine with the port numbers, but it's muddling some stuff we're trying to do with SEO and canonicalization. Does anyone know if there's a setting or setup to not produce the port numbers? (I'm sure I could rewrite the URLs by catching them at the appropriate point in the pipeline, but I'm hoping for a simpler way before I jump to that.)

Comment: Are you sure you've selected https binding in IIS for the site?

Comment: Also consider looking into this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273492/can-not-access-the-website-via-ssl

Comment: Did you add port to the `<site>` definition in config? If so that'll be why, the link manager is not very clever!

Answer (score 7):

The Sitecore `LinkManager` is indeed not so clever. We also experienced this issue with a mix of proxy servers and load balancers. To remove the ports, we have created a custom `LinkProvider` which removes the port if needed (untested code sample):

```
public class LinkProvider : Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider
{
   public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
   {
      var url = base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
      if (url.StartsWith("https://"))
      {
         url = url.Replace(":443", string.Empty);
      }

      return url;
   }
}
```

And configure the new `LinkProvider`:

```
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
      <providers>
        <add name="sitecore" set:type="Website.LinkProvider, Website" />
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by having the 'scheme' property in the configuration/sitecore/sites/site element of the web.config (or patched config) being set to 'http' explicitly, but making requests over SSL.  Removing this, or setting it to 'https' resolves the issue.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site patch:before="*[@name='website']"
                name="my_website"
                hostName="my_website.com"
                scheme="http" 
                ...
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug: 
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/913585

There is a patch for releases below 9.1 available here:
https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.93141/releases

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jan's findings: setting *externalPort* on the *site* node in the configuration convinces Sitecore to exclude the port in a generated URL.  I did a full write-up on my blog, including using the result for canonical URL tags.

http://findgnosis.com/2017/06/26/hiding-port-urls-produced-sitecores-linkmanager/

Comment: I think this could have been an upvote and a comment on Jan's answer.

Comment: This external link no longer works. Says the domain has expired. Please update your comment.

Comment: What version is this for? It doesn't seem to work in 8.1 which only seems to understand the 'port' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**LinkManager:**
You can cheat the LinkManager by adding `port="443" externalPort="80"` to your site-definition in `<sites>`. Don't know if this will cause other issues though.

```xml
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="website" port="443" externalPort="80" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**MediaManager:**
If you know the url, set the `Media.MediaLinkServerUrl`-setting, to prevent Sitecore from creating the wrong url. Otherwise...

```cs
class SslFriendlyMediaProvider : MediaProvider
{
    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
        var url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

        if(options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl)
            // https://example.com:443/a b?c=123 --> https://example.com/a%20b?c=123
            return new Uri(url).AbsoluteUri;

        return url;
    }
}
```

Config:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaProvider set:type="SslFriendlyMediaProvider, Assembly" />
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```